# Django, how to change settings.py base dir

Tags: python, django

I starting to work with Django and need some help. I need to change settings file folder.
My current path to settings file:

```
myproject
|--apps
|--assets
|--project
|-- |--settings.py
|--templates
|--manage.py
|--requerements.txt
```

I wanna change it to:

```
myproject
|--apps
|--assets
|--project
|-- |--settings
|-- |-- |--settings.py
|--templates
|--manage.py
|--requerements.txt
```

How i can do this?
Thank You!
P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for this:

```
myproject
|--apps
|--assets
|--project
|-- |--settings
|-- |-- |--__init__.py
|-- |-- |--dev.py
|-- |-- |--prod.py
|--templates
|--manage.py
|--requerements.txt
```

The `__init__.py` turns the `settings` directory into a Python directory and it allows you to have multiple files for settings: one for development and one for production systems. Depending on what code you put in `__init__.py` you can import the settings from `dev` or `prod`.